# C++ Accessing to begin()/end() methods of container inside a class

Tags: c++, class, methods, containers

i would like to access the begin() and end() methods of a Container inside a class without incurring in const_iterator to iterator conversion problems. So i made a get method to return the container and access it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class SpecialList {
  public:
    std::vector<int> getVett(void) const { return vettore; }

    void getFull(void) {
      std::vector<int>::iterator it1;

      for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        vettore.push_back(i);
    }

    void print(void) {
      std::vector<int>::iterator it1;

      std::cout << std::endl;

      for (it1 = vettore.begin(); it1 != vettore.end(); ++it1)
        std::cout << " " << *it1;

      std::cout << std::endl;
    }

  private:
   char some_data;
   std::vector<int> vettore;
};

int main(void) {
  std::cout << "Some output" << std::endl;

  SpecialList listspec;
  listspec.getFull();
  listspec.print();

  std::vector<int> pVet = listspec.getVett();

  std::cout << "Size = " << pVet.size() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "pVet[1] = " << pVet[1] << std::endl;

  std::vector<int>::iterator it2;

  std::cout << std::endl;

  for (it2 = listspec.getVett().begin(); it2 != listspec.getVett().end(); ++it2)
    std::cout << " " << *it2;

  std::cout << std::endl << "pVet[1] = " << pVet[1] << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The code works from a compiler perspective, but it gives the wrong output:

> Some output
>
> 0 **1** 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
>
> Size = 10
>
> pVet[1] = 1
>
> 0 **0** 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
>
> pVet[1] = 1

Why does it not read correctly the vector printing a 0 istead of a 1? Is this a good approach to access a container inside a class through iterators?

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you change `listspec.getVett()` to `pVet` in the for loop?

Comment: @immibis It works but i added pVet just for debugging purposes. I would like to not save the whole container returned from getVett() in another vector and just use iterators to work with it. That's why i would like to write  something like: `listspec.getVett().begin()` or `listspec.getVett().end()`.

Comment: @bolov Yeah, got distracted, and didn't manage to vote before. All taken care of now.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I think that question does not fully answer to this question. In fact it does not talk about how is possible that part of the vector is printed in the correct way here, and part not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `std::vector<int> getVett(void) const { return vettore; }` creates a copy of your vector `vettore`. You have to return a reference to your vector. Because of that you have undevined behaivor in your `for` loop. Change your function like this:

```
const std::vector<int>& getVett(void) const { return vettore; }
```

Since your function is `const` and your return reference is `const` you have to use `const_iterator`, `cbegin`and `cend` in your `for` loop.

```
std::vector<int>::const_iterator it2;
for (it2 = listspec.getVett().cbegin(); it2 != listspec.getVett().cend(); ++it2)
    std::cout << " " << *it2;
```

Note: You can use `auto` instead of `const_iterator`:

```
for (auto it2 = listspec.getVett().cbegin(); it2 != listspec.getVett().cend(); ++it2)
    std::cout << " " << *it2;
```

You also can you give up `const`:

```
std::vector<int>& getVett(void) { return vettore; } 

std::vector<int>::iterator it2;
for (it2 = listspec.getVett().begin(); it2 != listspec.getVett().end(); ++it2)
    std::cout << " " << *it2;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any way to achieve the same thing in C++03?

Comment: @hawake Which part of this answer, besides `auto`, doesn't work in C++03?

Comment: @immibis C++03 does not support cbegin() and cend().

Comment: @hawake Don't begin() and end() return const_iterators for const objects (or references)?

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thanks, that works. Without const, do i have to pay more attention to not overwrite data inside that vector while using iterators?

Comment: @immibis Yes, but as far as i tryed on my code, obviously the compiler gives you an error if you try to assign a const_iterator to an iterator (i.e. `std::vector<int>::iterator it1 = MyClass.ReturnConstIterator()` ), so you can't iterate in that way with a for loop, unless you convert the const_iterator in non-const one (but I'm finding it difficult to do in C++03).

Comment: @hawake ... so make `it1` a `...::const_iterator` instead of a `...::iterator`?

Comment: @immibis Please excuse me for the previous answer, i made confusion with the definition of const_iterators and in what they are different from non-const iterators. Thank you for the clarification.